# Multiple actions were found that match the request in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action

I use this service but I get this error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Post/List")]
public ApiMessageModel<object> Posts(List<FehrestBahaZaribKalaInputDto> models)
{}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Post")]
public ApiMessageModel<object> Post(FehrestBahaZaribKalaInputDto models)
{}
```

Comment: Please include the request in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the route to the HttpMethod attribute.

```
[HttpPost("api/Post/List")]
public ApiMessageModel<object> Posts(List<FehrestBahaZaribKalaInputDto> models)
{}

[HttpPost("api/Post")]
public ApiMessageModel<object> Post(FehrestBahaZaribKalaInputDto models)
{}
```